Source of an Alan Watts quote about soulmates
I am looking for a source to an Alan Watts… something. A clip I found on tiktok, of him talking about the existence of soulmate. The clip goes “…Soulmates do exist. It took me a long time to believe that….” I cannot find the full source anywhere, and I’d like to read the whole thing and share it with my boyfriend, but I don’t want to write it without a source to refer to.

I found this https://www.tiktok.com/@ambiencenight/video/7390688747051830560 For whatever reason it looks like there aren't transcripts online

I smell a fake. This audio is all over TilTok in fairly recent videos, but nowhere else that I can find. If you find any examples pre-2023 I would consider that significant.

Alan Watts seems to have been a one-man quote machine, but I could not find this one. Are you sure that this quote is from Watts?

This might be a parallel request from you but there's this Reddit thread looking for the same without luck, here. I'm not very familiar with Watts but that quote doesn't seem like him, e.g. he speaks about love and marriage here:

This morning I’m going to talk to you about a particularly virulent and dangerous form of divine madness which is called falling in love. Which is, from a practical point of view, one of the most insane things you can do, or that can happen to you... But if marriage were based more on the old idea of the reasonable contract between two people to bring up children, who may be expected at the best to be good friends and to allow each other to be persons that is to say in the ordinary sense of the word person to have their own freedom. Then if Love strikes it is tolerated within this arrangement provided you’re not going to be so unreasonable as to go on to say well life since I’ve fallen in love with somebody else I must marry them. Well that’s perfectly ridiculous.

